# create list of list with different length

Tags: r, data.table, xml2

I am trying to check if some words are nouns, verbs, etc.

So my final output should be a list of words and their classification.

Consider this script:

```
library(data.table)
library(xml2)
random_words_2 <- c("aa","ab","ac")
dic <- list()
dics <- list()
for (i in 1:3){
h <-     paste0("http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/",random_words_2[i])
html <- read_html(h)
oxford <- html_nodes(html, css = ".partOfSpeech")
n <- length(oxford)
for (m in 1:n) {
word <- as_list(oxford[[m]])
w <-  unlist(word[1])
dic[[m]] <- data.table(as.character(w))
}
dics <- rbindlist(dics, dic,use.names = TRUE,fill=FALSE)
}
```

Some words have more than one classification, like verbs, adverbs, etc. So, the list will have different sizes. 
I tried the code above, however the dics variable, which should give me the solution is:

> Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

But, the dic variable, gives:

> [[1]]
>        V1 1: noun
>
> [[2]]
>                V1 1: abbreviation

Can someone explain why this is happening and also, is there a more efficient way to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace the for loop with this one:

```
dics <- list()
for (i in 1:3){ 
h <- paste0("http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/",random_words_2[i]) 
html <- read_html(h) 
oxford <- html_nodes(html, css = ".partOfSpeech") 
n <- length(oxford) 
dic <- list() 
for (m in 1:n) 
{ 
    word <- as_list(oxford[[m]]) 
    w <- unlist(word[1]) 
    dic[[m]] <- data.table(as.character(w)) 
} 
dics <- c(dics, setNames(list(dic),random_words_2[i])) 
}
```

Comment: in your solution how would you relate the word with the output, for example: "aa" is "noun" and "abbreviation", "ab" is "noun", "noun", etc...?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want, can you post a short expected output?

Comment: word     classification  classification
ab             noun           abbreviation in a "matrix"  format, which the first column would be the words, and the other columns would be their respective classification

Comment: great, congrats! Thx